# How to update Top 1 column in SQL order by desc?

Tags: sql, t-sql

How to update Top 1 column in SQL order by desc?

Code has to update in sequence. We are not using any loop logic.

```
update table
set columna = 'newvalue'
where isnull(columna,'') = ''
and isnull(createddate,'') = ''
```

-- This has to be top 1 / order by desc - we have id sequence in the table. (I just created)

Comment: Using `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is fairly meaningless, and random.  Is there any column you want to use for the ordering?

Comment: @goofyui . . . How do you define the sequence of there are no columns in the table that specify the ordering?  And, if there are no such columns, what difference does it make?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  , CreateDate, Columna both has to be empty.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , i just added an identity column to have the sequence.. i will have the sequence

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order by `what` desc? Anyway:

```
UPDATE mySingleRow 
   SET columna = 'newvalue'
  FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * 
          FROM table 
         WHERE isnull(columna,'') = ''
           AND isnull(createddate,'') = ''
         ORDER BY columna DESC) mySingleRow
```